# dismax solr request handler MM , PS and Q.ALT

Tags: lucene, solr

I'm testing the dismax requesthandler , im trying to customize the mm  ( Minimum Match ) Parameter  ( i already looked at the documentation )

```
 <str name="mm">
 2<-2 3<-70% 5<-50%  
 </str>
 <int name="ps">100</int>
 <str name="q.alt">*:*</str>
```

I have 3 Questions :

- mm , i understood what it does , i want to verify if my param is ok ,

  > correct me if im wrong 
  >    2<-2 3<-70% 5<-50% stands for ?  :
  >
  > - if  1 or 2 terms match 100% of them
  > - if 3 to 4 match only 70% of them
  > - if 5 or more match only 50%
- ps : what is this param? Is it mandatory ?
- q.alt : the same i did not understand the utility of that one.

Can you provide me some advise for the best configuration of DisMax ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1: Your string would translate to

```
1-2 terms: match all terms
3 terms: total number of terms - 2 must match (i.e. 1 term must match :)
4-5 terms: 70% of the terms must match 
6+ terms: 50% of the terms must match
```

mm-string to achieve your requirement would be

```
2<%70 4<%50
```

A very good resource for mm strings can be found [here](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/util/doc-files/min-should-match.html).

2: The pf parameter is used to boost document relevance based on query terms occurring in close proximity of each other (as opposed to being scattered all over the document).

3: The q.alt parameter is used as a fallback query for cases when the client did not provide any search terms. In my interpretation, it is meant for use if you don't do any client-side query processing/transformation, but there could be other practical uses for it.

Comment: Thank you Karl ! 
i understood the mm param , for the others param i still septic for using them ;) 

another question :

does dismax support all the features like the standard requestHandler ? stopwords ? synonymes ? stemming ? did you hear about "edismax" ?

Thanks again !